# Listening ARP broadcasts

Tags: node.js, arp

I'd like to listen to ARP broadcasts coming from my router. Is it possible to do this somehow with node.js. I found an arpjs lib, but its dependency is not maintained, so I was not able to install it with the latest node. Isn't there a way to do this with vanilla node or with a different lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [cap module](https://github.com/mscdex/cap). It supports Windows with Winpcap, so I was able to test it with my PC. On Linux it requires libpcap and you need to run it as a root. A friend modified the example code to capture ARP broadcasts. They are more frequent than I expected and do not come only from the router, so it will be harder to filter the packets I need to.

```
var Cap = require('cap').Cap,  
    decoders = require('cap').decoders,  
    PROTOCOL = decoders.PROTOCOL;  

var c = new Cap(),    
    device = Cap.findDevice('192.168.0.10'),  
    //Ez fontos, ez parameterezi a libpcap/winpcap filtereit.  
    filter = 'arp',    
    bufSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024,    
    buffer = new Buffer(65535);    

var linkType = c.open(device, filter, bufSize, buffer);    

c.setMinBytes && c.setMinBytes(0);    

c.on('packet', function(nbytes, trunc) {    
  console.log('packet: length ' + nbytes + ' bytes, truncated? '    
              + (trunc ? 'yes' : 'no'));    

  // raw packet data === buffer.slice(0, nbytes)    

  if (linkType === 'ETHERNET') {    
    var ret = decoders.Ethernet(buffer);    

    //Ez is fontos, kulonben nem a megfelelore matchelsz.  
    if (ret.info.type === PROTOCOL.ETHERNET.ARP) {    
      console.log('Decoding ARP ...');    
    } else {  
      console.log('Unsupported Ethertype: ' + PROTOCOL.ETHERNET[ret.info.type]);    
    }  
  }    
});
```